# Why can a git merge commit have only one parent ref?

Tags: git

I've merged a fairly large commit into our master. There were some merge conflicts which had to be resolved. Everything is fine now but in history the other branch looks unmerged and the merge commit itself looks like a normal commit applied on top of master. The only hint now is the commit message. (It was not a --rebase merge.)

I'm just wondering how this can happen.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the commit graph.

Comment: Can you check the output of `git cat-file -p <yourCommit>` to actually see how many parent(s) are displayed? (or just `git log -1 --pretty=format:"%p" <yourCommit>`)

Comment: just one parent is displayed

Comment: How did you merge? Can you show us the command you used?

Comment: The usual reason for this is accidentally running `git reset` during the merge, which ends the merge.

Comment: Did you do it from command line or some UI of some SCM like github or gitlab?

Comment: no it was command line. perhaps I just had a `git reset` in between. Or a `git commit` during fixing of conflicts or something. Don't know.

Comment: `git merge --squash` also has this effect.